# Workflow running under App Step frequently Suspended but not always

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, app-step

I have Sharepoint 2019 on-premise. I have a Sharepoint 2013 workflow on a list (List A) which has an App step which updates items in other lists (List B and List C) based on a matching ID column. The matching items do exist in the other lists

Seemingly randomly the workflow will run successfully using the App Step but sometimes the Workflow is Suspended with the error:

'''
RequestorId: 5d0c1033-a398-f3cd-0000-000000000000. Details: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. Exception details: System.ApplicationException: HTTP 404 {"error":{"code":"-2130575338, System.ArgumentException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Item does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user."}}} {"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],"X-SharePointHealthScore":["0"],"X-SP-SERVERSTATE":["ReadOnly=0"],"DATASERVICEVERSION":["3.0"],"SPClientServiceRequestDuration":["28"],"SPRequestDuration":["51"],"SPRequestGuid":["5d0c1033-a398-f3cd-b06a-4406ed2a22e9"],"request-id":["5d0c1033-a398-f3cd-b06a-4406ed2a22e9"],"X-FRAME-OPTIONS":["SAMEORIGIN"],"MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices":["16.0.0.10401"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"X-MS-InvokeApp":["1; RequireReadOnly"],"Cache-Control":["max-age=0, private"],"Date":["Sat, 13 Jan 2024 13:28:25 GMT"],"Server":["Microsoft-IIS/10.0"],"X-AspNet-Version":["4.0.30319"],"X-Powered-By":["ASP.NET"]} at Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
'''

The items do exist in the other lists. I have already followed the steps provided here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/create-a-workflow-with-elevated-permissions-by-using-the-sharepoint-workflo).

And like I say, sometimes the workflow runs successfully and other times it is Suspended.